# How to deserialize or mimic the response type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am retrieve accounts:

```
    public async Task<JObject> GetAccount(string query)
    {
        var task = await Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
        var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
        return account;
    }
```

Regardless of whether `Client.Instance.GetAsync...` returns 200 or 400 or any other response type, when the response is deserialized to account `(JObject)`, **the response is always 200.**

**How do we get the response type from our JObject?**

Comment: Look at the other properties of `task` (which is not a `Task` and should be renamed).  This has nothing to do with `JObject`.

Comment: @slaks so if i wanted to return both the response type and the pay load (JObject) what would be the most functional way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Return an `HttpRequestMessage` or set properties of `Response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the response type from the response of the inner query. The action is basically acting as a proxy. Use the response from the internal query to construct the response being passed on to the calling client.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount(string query) {
    //get the query response NOTE: assuming it is HttpResponseMessage
    var queryResponse = await Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
    //get the status code for pass through
    var queryResponseStatus = queryResponse.StatusCode;
    //content to be passed on in the response
    var jsonString = await queryResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //create response message with status code
    var responseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(queryResponseStatus);
    //assign the content of the response
    responseMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    //return the result
    return ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
}
```

Comment: I also probably shouldn't be doing double serialization and deserialization

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' there is no serialization or deserialization in this answer. The raw string response is being passed on.